# Connecting with office365 fails with 401 but user is authorized

Tags: powershell, office365, exchange-server

I had an exchange script running that has this code at the beginning:

```
##Exchange Service
$service = New-Object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExchangeService([Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExchangeVersion]::Exchange2016)
$service.Url = new-object Uri("https://outlook.office365.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx");
$service.Credentials = New-Object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.WebCredentials($MailboxName,$passwd)

##Target Folder Binding
$folderid = new-object  Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.FolderId([Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.WellKnownFolderName]::Inbox,$targetMailboxName)
$InboxFolder = [Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.Folder]::Bind($service,$folderid)
```

This code did work in the past but now I get an 401 unauthorized error message when trying to connect to the exchange server.

The strange thing is, I tryed to verify my authorization [here](https://testconnectivity.microsoft.com/tests/O365EwsAccess/input) and after the test every checkmark is green.

So my account is authorized but still can't access the information when running it via powershell code.

Any idea what I could try to solve this problem?

Comment: Basic authentication might be disabled for EWS on your tenant.

Comment: @bluuf oh yeah, i can only do it with OAuth now. Any idea if I just need to change a bit code to get it to work?

Comment: I also want to know the answer to this!